# SlowCheetah fails with Visual Studio Online hosted build

Tags: slowcheetah, azure-devops

I have created a hosted build for my console application that uses SlowCheetah for app.config transforms but it fails with the following errors:

C:\a\src\WorkFolderHosted\Axe Integration Project\HPAxeGlue\AxeNAB\Properties\SlowCheetah\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets(33,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\a\src\WorkFolderHosted\Axe Integration Project\HPAxeGlue\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.10.3\tools\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll" because it was not found. [C:\a\src\WorkFolderHosted\Axe Integration Project\HPAxeGlue\AxeNAB\AxeNAB.csproj]

Same error for files SlowCheetah.NuGet.template.proj, SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets, SlowCheetah.Xdt.dll

My Solution is set up as follows:
-Visual Studio 2012 with source stored in Visual Studio Online
-I have enabled Nuget Package Restore
-I have added SlowCheetah to the relevant projects via NuGet
-Local build and transforms work fine
-I do not know what c:\a\ is, I assume the build process is creating this folder

I read the following blog http://sedodream.com/2012/12/24/SlowCheetahBuildServerSupportUpdated.aspx however SlowCheetah does not create a packageRestore.proj file as described.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by:

- deleting $solution.nuget\nuget.exe and nuget.targets
- deleting $solution\packages
- Right clicking the solution in Visual Studio and clicking 'Enable NuGet Package Restore'
- Checking the changes back into TFS

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Slow Cheetah failing to work, did not notice your question until after I posted mine.

[Slow Cheetah stopped working in Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/view/Reviews/5)

The fix was to go to this page and install the Slow Cheetah Visual Studio extension:

[Slow Cheetah Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/view/Reviews/5)

Slow Cheetah had worked on my machine for years after installing it from the NuGet package; no idea why I would suddenly need to install this extension, but it worked.